# Auto login into router running Busybox

Tags: init-script, busybox, autologin

My router runs Linux with embedded Busybox. I'd like to autologin and run a web browser. Here is the `/etc/inittab` file:

```
# /etc/inittab init(8) configuration for BusyBox
#
# Copyright (C) 1999-2004 by Erik Andersen 
#
#
# Note, BusyBox init doesn't support runlevels.  The runlevels field is
# completely ignored by BusyBox init. If you want runlevels, use sysvinit.
#
#
# Format for each entry: :::
#
# : WARNING: This field has a non-traditional meaning for BusyBox init!
#
#   The id field is used by BusyBox init to specify the controlling tty for
#   the specified process to run on.  The contents of this field are
#   appended to "/dev/" and used as-is.  There is no need for this field to
#   be unique, although if it isn't you may have strange results.  If this
#   field is left blank, it is completely ignored.  Also note that if
#   BusyBox detects that a serial console is in use, then all entries
#   containing non-empty id fields will _not_ be run.  BusyBox init does
#   nothing with utmp.  We don't need no stinkin' utmp.
#
# : The runlevels field is completely ignored.
#
# : Valid actions include: sysinit, respawn, askfirst, wait, once,
#                                  restart, ctrlaltdel, and shutdown.
#
#       Note: askfirst acts just like respawn, but before running the specified
#       process it displays the line "Please press Enter to activate this
#       console." and then waits for the user to press enter before starting
#       the specified process.
#
#       Note: unrecognised actions (like initdefault) will cause init to emit
#       an error message, and then go along with its business.
#
# : Specifies the process to be executed and it's command line.
#
# Note: BusyBox init works just fine without an inittab. If no inittab is
# found, it has the following default behavior:
         ::once:/usr/sbin/usbconsole
         ::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS
         ::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/reboot
         ::shutdown:/etc/init.d/rc.shutdown
         ::shutdown:/sbin/swapoff -a
         ::shutdown:/bin/umount -a -r
         ::restart:/sbin/init
#
# if it detects that /dev/console is _not_ a serial console, it will
# also run:
#         tty2::askfirst:/bin/sh
#         tty3::askfirst:/bin/sh
#         tty4::askfirst:/bin/sh
#
# Boot-time system configuration/initialization script.
# This is run first except when booting in single-user mode.
#
# ::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS
# ::sysinit:/linuxrc

# /bin/sh invocations on selected ttys
#
# Note below that we prefix the shell commands with a "-" to indicate to the
# shell that it is supposed to be a login shell.  Normally this is handled by
# login, but since we are bypassing login in this case, BusyBox lets you do
# this yourself...
#
# Start an "askfirst" shell on the console (whatever that may be)

::askfirst:-/bin/sh

# Start an "askfirst" shell on /dev/tty2-4
# tty2::askfirst:-/bin/sh
# tty3::askfirst:-/bin/sh
# tty4::askfirst:-/bin/sh

# /sbin/getty invocations for selected ttys
# tty4::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty5
# tty5::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty6

# Example of how to put a getty on a serial line (for a terminal)
#::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 115200 vt100

My router runs Linux embedded with Busybox. I'd like to autologin and run a web browser on boot. Here is the `/etc/inittab file`:
#
# Example how to put a getty on a modem line.
#::respawn:/sbin/getty 57600 ttyS2

# Stuff to do when restarting the init process
# ::restart:/sbin/init

# Stuff to do before rebooting
# ::ctrlaltdel:/sbin/reboot
# ::shutdown:/bin/umount -a -r
# ::shutdown:/sbin/swapoff -a
```

Comment: what have you tried ? besides inittab is of no use here. have you check ssh and keys ? have you check any of the link on the right (Related) ?

Comment: I tried to edit the inittab file so that when I boot up the router it can automatically login as root into the desktop mode. I aslo tried deleting the file since the inittab file said  BusyBox init works just fine without an inittab. If no inittab is found, it has the following default behavior:(code listed above), but when I rebooted the system it hang at the cisco logo.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a **slightly** late answer, but I've decided to add it anyway.

Hanging at the Cisco logo (or whatever else) is the *expected* behaviour in the case when the `/etc/inittab` file is empty. The answer depends on how you want to log into the machine. Uncommenting the line:

```
::respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyS0 115200 vt100
```

allows you to provide login prompt on `/dev/ttyS0`. Assuming that you have connected over serial `/dev/ttyS0` (be sure that this is in fact your interface, e.g., at my *machine* it is `/dev/ttyPS0`), the auto-login can be realised by adding:

```
ttyPS0::respawn:/bin/login -f <user>
```

This should auto log-in you as the `<user>`.
The other approach that uses `/sbin/getty` and custom-made auto-login utility is described [here](https://wiki.gumstix.com/index.php/AutoLogin).

If you want to automatically log-in using, e.g., `/dev/tty3`, you can modify the example. The auto-start of browser will depend on the X and the browser you use. I would modify the `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` in your `${HOME}` directory (typically `/home/<user>`) by adding at the end something like:

```
startx
google-chrome-stable &
```

Note, however, that if you're connected to the router over some serial/USB cable this may not work.

Comment: You likely want to add a leading dash `-/bin/login` as explained in my answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/474733/32558

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 I'm definitely sure that `Ctrl+C` works without the leading dash, I've just checked it.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out. I've tried it again and I confirm Ctrl + C does not work on my setup with `::respawn:/bin/login -f user0` without the leading dash. This is the precise setup: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/8815312cad053d0284c4d91bfbf36a1e9ea207af#qemu-buildroot-setup and this is how I modify the inittab on that setup: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/8815312cad053d0284c4d91bfbf36a1e9ea207af#tty BusyBox 1.28.4. It would be cool to understand how our setups are different.

Comment: @CiroSantilli新疆改造中心六四事件法轮功 Well... To be honest I didn't use Buildroot, but rather I prepared my custom bash script that downloads, builds and creates the whole tool-chain together with rootfs, custom device trees for our platform, etc. to be sure that I can always resurrect it. I used: `binutils 2.27`, `busybox 1.24.2`, `musl 1.1.19 `, `musl 1.1.19` and `linux 4.9.22`. Yes, I know, `Linux 4.9.22` is _ancient_. I reviewed your link and I think the main difference is busybox and libc versions. `/etc/inittab` looks similar to mine.

Comment: Thanks for giving the specs. busybox version and config should be all that matters I think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a router to test, but at least on Buildroot + BusyBox + QEMU the following fstab entry logs you in automatically and makes everything seem to work normally:

```
::respawn:-/bin/sh
```

as I've explained at: [How to login automatically without typing the root username or password in Buildroot BusyBox init?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299408/how-to-login-automatically-without-typing-the-root-username-or-password-in-build/300152#300152)

Don't forget the leading `-`! Otherwise TTY interaction is a bit broken, e.g. you lose the ability to do Ctrl + C to kill the foreground program.

If you want to login as another user, you can use `/bin/login` as mentioned at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/434799/32558 but you likely want to add the dash in front of it as well, for the same reason as `/bin/sh`:

```
::respawn:-/bin/login -f user0
```